# Need HA, multi-datacenter, memory based, key-value solution

Tags: redis, memcached, high-availability, voldemort

New to space and I have been attempting to narrow down the potentials but seem to be spinning my wheels.

I are storing String -> String lookups.  The key and value are likely under 15 bytes each. A userid -> server they are connected to.

- We have multiple data centers
- Need ability to read/write locally in low ms range.
  I tried writing to a remote Redis and it seems tied to network latency which is too slow.  This rules out simple M-S solutions.
- Need HA both for node failure and entire data center failure.  Implies replication
- Prefer solution to provide ability to query multiple queries in one call. MGET
- A few hundred thousand SET per second and a few million GET per second
- Free for commercial use (could pay for instance so Riak is possible)
- I need only for the solution to support GET, SET, DELETE, [MGET prefered]

Active - Active / Multi Master / Clusters with replication - I am only vaguely familiar with these terms and their tradeoffs.

http://blog.nahurst.com/visual-guide-to-nosql-systems
In CAP Theorem I probably want a AP solution but flip flop that a lot.  It is further confusing when a typical CP solution can be augmented with replication solutions such as Dynamite/Dynamo/Twemproxy/etc.

My shortlist but open to any solution.

- Redis Cluster
- Redis+Sentinel with Dynomite
- Memcached with Dynomite
- Voldemort

Any idea how I should go about finding a solution for my need or does anyone have a solution in mind?

Comment: Active/Active (Multi Master) implies that the same data can be updated at both sites, whereas your 2nd bullet is a little vague whether that's a requirement or not.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Sorry, which one is unclear?  The second bullet point is a need to read/write the data quickly and this is a must have.

Comment: Is there a requirement for the same data be writable at both sites at the same time?

Comment: Kindof.  It is EXTREMELY unlikely for the exact same key to be written at the same time.  Perhaps impossible.  However each server should not incur latency for either a read or write beyond a few ms.

Think of this kind of like storing which server IP address a username is connected to.  Think of DNS.  Since a username is unique and unlikely to be logged into more than one server there isn't a need to write/update the same data at the same time.

Comment: **Disclaimer I**: the question strongly calls for an opinion so I'm still debating whether to vote on closing it. **Disclaimer II**: I'm a Redis fanboy and work for a commercial company that specializes in it.

Comment: How would you solve this with Redis then.  Inter data center writes to a Master can take 80-104ms depending on the datacenter.  This makes writes prohibitive.  Have you any experience with solutions that overcome this such as Dynomite or the newly released Redis Cluster.  And if you have a commercial solution that solves this my company may be interested.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75875/discussion-between-itamar-haber-and-redboy).

Comment: Also evaluate aerospike , I would suit all of your requirements .